# Configure proxy for azure client(SDK version- 1.0.0-beta2) in Java

Tags: azure, proxy

I am using the following Azure clients with 1.0.0-beta2 version,

ComputeManagementClientImpl client = new ComputeManagementClientImpl(credentials);

ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClientImpl(credentials);

NetworkManagementClientImpl networkClient = new NetworkManagementClientImpl(credentials);

StorageManagementClientImpl storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClientImpl(credentials);

How do i configure proxy for the following clients?